# How to find max of mysql varchar column

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this with a var char field `reference_number`
actually i need to get the max of number in that field

```
 <<student>>

 |`id` | `reference_number`(varchar(25))
 --------------------------
 | 1   | L250
 | 2   | SP521
 | 3   | S120
 | 4   | SP500
 | 5   | S122
```

the desired result is 521 because if we are avoiding the non numeric value then it will come like this

```
|`id` | `reference_number`
 --------------------------
 | 1   | 250
 | 2   | 521
 | 3   | 120
 | 4   | 500
 | 5   | 122
```

how to get the the value 521 from the table

Comment: Can you able to use user-defined function ? If so, it will be easy process.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have extracted 'reference_number' as shown in the second snippet from the first snippet. if so, try :::

```
select max(cast (reference_number as int)) from student
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the number 521 (and all the numbers from the *reference_number* column) you could try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE reference_number REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

And then you can add an order by statement.

Comment: can i use any extra condition in where part?

Comment: I think it should be OK. Give it a try and let me know if it worked well.

Comment: its workingfine..i have an extra column school_ID...the query need to be like this    SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE reference_number REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' and school_ID='10';

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Comment: please go through it...SELECT * FROM student WHERE reference_number REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' and school_ID='10'   means an extra condition needed like school_ID wise , the above query showing null result

Comment: Does the table in the solution, without any additional clauses, shows the numbers? Also, is School_id a number column, or a string column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148292/discussion-between-muhammad-ali-and-assafs).